# cs-cart error: We were unable to find what you were looking

Tags: php, laravel, cs-cart

After uploading a product catalog, when the products were created, a fake link seems to be added to each product (the same for all) and therefore, when I go to the product detail, I get a "404 Page not found" Error... Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

```
    Oops!
We were unable to find what you were looking for.
The page you have requested cannot be found.
Error code: Page Not Found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guess that the catalog is loaded via import and smth goes wrong. here are some  standard product misconfiguration leading to 404:

- product has Disabled status;
- product has no price;
- product has no category;
- product has categories but all of them have Disabled status;
- product is not assigned to any storefront/vendor;
- product is not premoderated for Multivendor;
- product is imported with SEO name and it is duplicated in database;

of course, custom add-ons might cause issue too.

also you may use the following workaround:

- take a particular product;
- create it manually in CS-Cart with correct properties;
- export it to CSV;
- compare to what you have in CSV (or XML) and add;

Answer (score 0):

1. Please enable developer mode

   https://docs.cs-cart.com/4.4.x/developer_guide/getting_started/configuring_cscart.html
2. Check source code of the **Oops!** page and you can see the error at the bottom